# CSS center image, right align text

Tags: css, header, alignment, block

I'm working on a site for a friend at http://blueridgemusclecars.com/ . I want the logo at the top center, and the phone number and location right aligned, but I would like the text in the same plane horizontally as the logo. Right now the text is below and to the right of the logo. Here is my CSS for the header, any ideas?

```
 header {
    width:100%;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:2;
}

h1 {
    padding:45px 20px 37px 26px; 
    /*background:url(../images/h1-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;*/
    /*float:right;*/

}
    h1 a {
        display:block;
        width:500px;
        height:278px;
        text-indent:-999em;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:url(../images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
.address {
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:28px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#b22300;
}
.phone {
    display:block;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm by no means versed in CSS, just trying to throw a site together for a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `.fright` class to have a negative top margin.

```
.fright { margin-top: -100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The markup could probably be reworked a little (e.g., not sure why the link and image are in an `<h1>`), but easiest thing on this page I think is adding the following to your CSS:

```
.wrapper { height: 300px; } //reduce empty space
.fright  { margin-top: -195px; } //align phone number with image bottom
```

That looks pretty good in Chrome anyway...good luck!